# multiple definition

Tags: c++

My code had an error about not defining the `operator<`. I corrected the `operator<` problem in my code by overloading it. When I compile it, there was no error there but it has lots of errors about multidefinition. My code is:

```
int Vector3D::operator < (const Vector 3D &vector) const
{
 if(x<vector.x)
   return 1;
 else
   return 0;
}
```

Here are some of the lines:

```
debug/src/common/propagation-delay-model_1.o: In function `empty':
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/limits:1044: multiple definition of `ns3::Vector3D::operator<(ns3::Vector3D const&) const'
debug/src/core/vector_1.o:/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/../src/core/vector.h:118: first defined here
debug/src/common/propagation-loss-model_1.o: In function `empty':
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/new:94: multiple definition of `ns3::Vector3D::operator<(ns3::Vector3D const&) const'
debug/src/core/vector_1.o:/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/../src/core/vector.h:118: first defined here
debug/src/common/jakes-propagation-loss-model_1.o: In function `empty':
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/new:94: multiple definition of `ns3::Vector3D::operator<(ns3::Vector3D const&) const'
debug/src/core/vector_1.o:/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/../src/core/vector.h:118: first defined here
debug/src/common/cost231-propagation-loss-model_1.o: In function `empty':
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/limits:1044: multiple definition of `ns3::Vector3D::operator<(ns3::Vector3D const&) const'
debug/src/core/vector_1.o:/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/../src/core/vector.h:118: first defined here
debug/src/common/spectrum-propagation-loss-model_1.o: In function `~BandInfo':
/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/debug/ns3/type-id.h:392: multiple definition of `ns3::Vector3D::operator<(ns3::Vector3D const&) const'
debug/src/core/vector_1.o:/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/../src/core/vector.h:118: first defined here
debug/src/common/friis-spectrum-propagation-loss_1.o: In function `~BandInfo':
/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/debug/ns3/vector.h:118: multiple definition of `ns3::Vector3D::operator<(ns3::Vector3D const&) const'
debug/src/core/vector_1.o:/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/../src/core/vector.h:118: first defined here
debug/src/node/spectrum-phy_1.o: In function `~TypeId':
/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/debug/ns3/type-id.h:392: multiple definition of `ns3::Vector3D::operator<(ns3::Vector3D const&) const'
debug/src/core/vector_1.o:/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/../src/core/vector.h:118: first defined here
debug/src/internet-stack/ipv6-l3-protocol_1.o: In function `new_allocator':
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/new:94: multiple definition of `ns3::Vector3D::operator<(ns3::Vector3D const&) const'
debug/src/core/vector_1.o:/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/../src/core/vector.h:118: first defined here
debug/src/routing/olsr/olsr-routing-protocol_1.o: In function `~Association':
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/new:94: multiple definition of `ns3::Vector3D::operator<(ns3::Vector3D const&) const'
debug/src/core/vector_1.o:/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/build/../src/core/vector.h:118: first defined here
debug/src/routing/olsr/test/bug780-test_1.o: In function `new_allocator':
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/new:94: multiple definition of `ns3::Vector3D::operator<(ns3::Vector3D const&) const'
```

Comment: please post some of the source code from where you have defined the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are defining a function in a header file, so it gets defined in every source file that includes it. Either declare it `inline` (which allows multiple definitions), or move the implementation into a source file (so it's only defined once). **EDIT**: Or move the definition inside the class definition, which also makes it inline. (Thanks David.)

Comment: +1 Another option is actually defining the method inside the class definition, which has the same effect as adding `inline` to the method definition outside of the class definition.